# Lengthy piped command output hangs when passed to sed or awk

Tags: bash, macos, awk, sed, pipe

## Background

I'm working on a change to my CI build that triggers a command which runs my Xcode unit test output. These tests log an extremely verbose amount of information – so much so that I exceed the 4 MB log capture limit and my build gets terminated. As far as I can tell, there's no way for me to make it less verbose (one way I came up with is going to require a change to the command that runs the tests, [which I'm working on](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7577).

## My Workaround

So I decided to get clever and try filtering my output with `sed`, like so:

```
test_running_command | sed '/xctest\[/d; /^$/d'
```

The `sed` command works when I run it on a file, filtering out lines containing `xctest[` and empty lines, as intended. But when I incorporate this into my CI build, I see output streamed to a certain point, and then it just stops. After 10 minutes, my CI build gets killed anyway, before I had the chance to hit the 4 MB limit.

## The Question

Why is `sed` hanging like this?

## Troubleshooting Performed

- I tried using `awk`, like so, which similarly hangs.

  ```
  test_running_command | awk '$0 !~ /xctest\[/ && $0 !~ /^$/ {print}'
  ```
- I tried a command [from this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61833/182046) to turn on line buffering for the original command, which just hung at a different place.

  ```
  script -q /dev/null test_running_command | <sed or awk command from above>
  ```
- As suggested by @CharlesDuffy in a comment, I used `tee` to write to file what goes into the pipe, and determined that the left side of the pipe definitely gets much further than the right. I observed (on my local machine) that while the output to the console was frozen, before_filter.txt was continuing to progress. This is the line I used:

  ```
  test_running_command | tee before.txt | sed '/xctest\[/d; /^$/d' | tee after.txt
  ```
- As suggested by @LuisMuñoz in a comment, I tried using stdbuf (after installing with `brew install coreutils`) to disable buffering into and out of `sed`. I didn't see a difference in behavior. Output still froze at an arbitrary point.

  ```
  test_running_command | gstdbuf -i0 -o0 sed '/xctest\[/d; /^$/d'
  ```

Comment: Are you sure the output buffer is getting re-filled after the place it dumps content up to?

Comment: One useful debugging step is to put `tee`s at both ends: `test_running_command | tee before_filter | sed ... | tee after_filter`

Comment: I think we might need a bit more info about the environment you are running this in... Is it possible that you need to encapsulate both your test and the filter... something like `sh -c 'test_running_command | sed "/xctest\[/d; /^\$/d"'`?

Comment: This worked for me `stdbuf -i0 -o0` placed before `awk`, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49621451/2834978).

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I'm running on a Mac, and it doesn't look like that's a built-in command.

Comment: @MichaelBack It's a line in a script being invoked

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have no reason to think the buffer's not getting re-filled, since the command goes further than that when run on its own. Using `tee` is an interesting idea, except since this is happening on a CI server (Travis) I need to find out whether and how I can look at those files after the fact

Comment: May be `stdbuf` is [present in your mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/222730) but as `gstdbuf`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Please take a look at my updated last bullet point. Using `tee`, I determined that the left side of the pipe definitely gets further than the right side of the pipe

Comment: @LuisMuñoz As mentioned in the answer you linked to, it's available as part of a Homebrew module (`coreutils`). Especially because this is a temporary workaround, I'd rather use tools built in if possible, but even then, I still saw the same behavior. Output to the console freezes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the `-l` flag for `sed`. Apparently that turns on line-buffering mode, which produced the desired effect. I wonder if it was having problems because its buffer was getting overrun by the incredibly long lines produced. Regardless, this command ultimately worked:

```
 test_running_command | sed -l '/xctest\[/d; /^$/d'
```

As a side note, I had one test that was taking longer than 10 minutes on the CI server, and without log output, that was causing a timeout. I put a single `printf` statement inside its outer loop that produced just enough log output so the build didn't get killed. The `printf` line didn't get filtered by the `sed` command, so this is perfect.