# Moving around the input

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a simple text editor using bash script. I want the user to be able to edit his whole text. Naturally, there is no problem with moving around the line using left and right arrow keys, but I also want to move up and down with up and down arrows. Here is my code:

```
declare -a arr
while read -re; do
   arr+=( "$REPLY" )
done
```

Comment: so, what's your problem?

Comment: When I'm inputting my text I can't go back with my cursor to the upper line just like I can with moving the cursor left and right on the line I'm at atm. I was wondering if there is any function that let me place my cursor in upper or lower line when pressing the arrow key.

Comment: I don't think there is, but this should still be in your original question. You probably need to redraw the whole screen to achieve this kind of cursor control

Comment: There is nothing simple about writing a text editor in `bash`. You need access to the full screen, whereas `bash` is designed to read a stream of bytes.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49621451/2834978) that moves the cursor around to print text in 2 columns.

Comment: Thanks for the link :)